# Solving an Absolute Value Inequality

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

**The Question:**

> $|x^2+x-1|-|3x+1|<x^2-2$

I don't really know how to work with absolute values, besides basic ones. 
Here is my attempt at simplifying, can someone tell me where I messed up and give some hints on how to continue?

$|x^2+x-1|-|3x+1|<x^2-2$

$|x^2+x-1|<x^2-2+|3x+1|$

$x^2+x-1<x^2-2+3x+1$ or $x^2+x-1>-x^2+2-3x-1$

$2x>1$ or $x^2+2x-1>0$

**Answer:**

> $x<-1 $ or $x>-1+\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Your mistake is in the third line. If $|a|<b+|c|$, it does not follow that $a<b+c$ or $a>b-c$. You are confusing this with $|a|<b\iff -b<a<b$ (assuming $b$ is nonnegative).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have four cases which depend on the sign of $(x^2+x-1)$ and $(3x+1)$ (the arguments of the absolute values).

> $1)$ If $x\geq -1/3$ then you have to solve
>   $$|x^2+x-1|-(3x+1)<x^2-2$$
>   or $|x^2+x-1|<x^2+3x-1$.

Two subcases:

> $1.1)$ For $-1/3\leq x< (\sqrt{5}-1)/2$, it becomes
>   $$-(x^2+x-1)<x^2+3x-1$$
>   or $0<2x^2+4x-2$ which holds in this interval for $\sqrt{2}-1<x$.
>
> $1.2)$ For $x\geq (\sqrt{5}-1)/2$, we have
>   $$(x^2+x-1)<x^2+3x-1$$
>   or $0<2x$, $x>0$ which always satisfied in this interval.

---

> $2)$ If $x< -1/3$ then you have to solve
>   $$|x^2+x-1|+(3x+1)<x^2-2$$
>   or $|x^2+x-1|<x^2-3x-3$.

Two subcases:

> $2.1)$ Now for $-(\sqrt{5}+1)/2<x<-1/3 $, it becomes
>   $$-(x^2+x-1)<x^2-3x-3.$$
>   or $0<2x^2-2x-4$ which holds in this interval for $x<-1$.
>
> $2.2)$ For $x\leq -(\sqrt{5}+1)/2$, we have
>   $$(x^2+x-1)<x^2-3x-3.$$
>   or $0<-2x-2$, $x<-1$ which always satisfied in this interval.

---

Finally, putting all together, we have that the solution is:
$$\mbox{$x>\sqrt{2}-1$ (1.1 and 1.2) or $x<-1$ (2.1 and 2.2).}$$

Comment: The first one would simplify to $x>0$ or $x<-1-\sqrt{2}$ and the second one to $x>2$

Comment: Can you explain how you got $(\sqrt5-1)/2$ for subcase 1.1?

Comment: @Anonymous For $x\geq -1/3$, $x^2+x-1=0$  at $(\sqrt5-1)/2$.

Comment: How did you find the number $(\sqrt{5}-1)/2$ though?

Comment: @Anonymous $(\sqrt{5}-1)/2$ is one of the roots of the quadratic equation $x^2+x-1=0$.

Comment: Oh, don't know why I didn't get that the first time, thanks